# android ripple animation layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I see the UI is amazed picture:

[image]

The right arrow is animation.

I found this github.com/skyfishjy/android-ripple-background

But I don't know how to complete the UI

Now : I try to complete this UI,but something wrong.

The picture is

[image]

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="150dp"
          android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
          android:padding="16dp"
          android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
          android:gravity="bottom"
          android:layout_weight="2">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0px"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="3dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:text="@string/drawer_header_text"/>

<com.skyfishjy.library.RippleBackground
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/content"
        app:rb_color="#0099CC"
        app:rb_radius="32dp"
        app:rb_rippleAmount="6"
        app:rb_duration="6000"
        app:rb_scale="6">

 <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:id="@+id/centerImage"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_arrow_wh"/>
    </com.skyfishjy.library.RippleBackground>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<com.skyfishjy.library.RippleBackground
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/content"
    app:rb_color="#0099CC"
    app:rb_radius="32dp"
    app:rb_rippleAmount="6"
    app:rb_duration="6000"
    app:rb_scale="6">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:id="@+id/centerImage"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_arrow_wh"/> 

</com.skyfishjy.library.RippleBackground>
```

**app:rb_color="#0099CC"** change it to your desired **color**

**android:layout_width="wrap_content"** change it to your **64dp**

**android:layout_height="wrap_content"** change it to your **64dp**

Comment: The only pitfall in this library, attributes can't be set programmatically.